# Show that every decreasing function $f$: $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ measurable

Tags: measure-theory, proof-writing

I have the following question from an elementary course on Measure Theory:

> Show that every decreasing function $f$: $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\space/ \space \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ measurable (where $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is the Borel Sigma Algebra on $\mathbb{R}$)

Any hints to prove this result would be appreciated :)

Comment: Look at $f^{-1} (-\infty,\alpha]$.

Comment: You could have a slightly less general title. Measure theory is a fairly broad subject.

Comment: Check [this](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~mingfeng/5111%20spring%202011/my/rhw5/rhw5.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Look at the definition of measurability you learned. You probably proved a whole list of equivalence conditions for measurability. Of these, one is going to be particularly easy to establish for a decreasing function. Try to think geometrically about each measurability criterion and think about it in the case of decreasing functions.